# How to start Power Automate workflow from code/spfx solution web part?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate, spfx, spf

Is it possible to trigger start of Power Automate workflow and pass parameters to workflow through spfx solution/webpart (with React)? Without premium connector.
I only found one way but it is premium connector and we can't use those.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have permission to use the officially provided triggers, it is recommended that you consider customizing the triggers:
This is the official tutorial for your reference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/create-triggers-custom-connectors/

But creating custom triggers also requires a specific license, and you need to make sure you have sufficient permissions.

Another way is to send a Graph api request in the button click event to create a record, and then trigger the flow through flow's [when a record is created]. This method will have some delays.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have spfx solution/webpart experience - however maybe try triggering your worfklow from a button and then have spfx calling `Select(<button name>)` ...